# special character is rejected by tomcat cookie parser

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies

When I am trying to send a cookie from my android code to server-side code , the cookie parser does not accept the '@' character in value field i.e. tomcat's cookie parser reject this character when parsing mime headers to cookie. I tried using other special characters instead of '@' and those are working. Can anyone help me?

Example-: One of the mime header field is 
"cookie =  [_user=vishalgoyal2612@gmail.com]"
but the corresponding cookie to this field is "_user = vishalgoyal2612"

Comment: Try setting the system property `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.CookieSupport.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0` to `true` (e.g. in catalina.properties etc.)

Comment: No , it's not working!!

Comment: Did you restart tomcat after you changed the property?

Comment: Actually I had to set org.apache.tomcat.util.http. ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0 to true. And Now it's working. Thanks

Comment: Nice. I suggest you add that as an answer, and you'll be able to accept it after a certain waiting time. It will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0 to true.

Here is the source - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

Comment: Or, you know, don't violate the various cookie specs.