# Java Spring cuts email cookie in half

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cookies

I'm trying to read cookie with an email address. I know, that the cookie is saved correctly and contains the full email address (for Example "mymail@test.com"). However, when I look at the cookie in the request Object, it has the value "mymail" the @ and everything behind it is missing.

Does anyone have an idea why?

FYI:
My Web-Application uses Spring Security and runs on Tomcat.

Comment: You have got to give some more info, because WebUtils class usage is working fine with me for "mymail@test.com" . Please be sure that cookie has got the right value stored in your request object

Comment: You could alternatively also try "Cookie[] requestCookies = request.getCookies();" and check if the value is read correctly here or not.

Comment: The cookie is also incomplete in the request object, but when I check it with EditThisCookie (browserplugin) it is complete.

Comment: Somehow, your plugin "EditThisCookie" is manipulating this cookie value, because I don't know of any other reason for this behaviour. If you want you can refer this link https://www.journaldev.com/1956/java-servlet-cookies-example. It shows the basic java code to read/write cookies

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Tomcat problem. I was able to fix it by editing the Catalina properties.
I've set org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0 to true.

For more Info look here: [special character is rejected by tomcat cookie parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573102/special-character-is-rejected-by-tomcat-cookie-parser)

Comment: This isn't a *problem* with Tomcat *per se*, because it's adhering to a specification. The best thing for you to do would be to encode your cookie values (and, if necessary, cookie names) in such a way as to avoid any problematic characters. `base64` encoding is a very popular choice.